# Regex to select CSS declaration blocks that don't have certain color values

Tags: css, regex

Let's say I have the following CSS. I need a regular expression that grabs entire declaration blocks (selector, opening bracket, contents, closing bracket) that *do not* have the folowing colors in them: `#f518e2` and `#22f1e6`

```
.foo{
  color: #f518e2;
  box-spacing: border-box;
}

#bar{
  color: #e4e4e4;
  box-spacing: border-box;
}

biz.baz{
  background: #22f1e6;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

So in this case, I would want to grab:

```
#bar{
  color: #e4e4e4;
  box-spacing: border-box;
}
```

Assumptions:

- There are hundreds of selectors in the file
- The syntax is always valid CSS, but spacing, new lines, and use of semi-colons is inconsistent. For example:

```
#bar{   color: #e4e4e4;   
box-spacing: border-box; }biz.baz
{   
  background: #22f1e6;   
font-size: 30px; }
```

I've tried something like this: `/\w*[#.]?\w+\s*{[^\{\}]+}/g` which selects entire declaration blocks, but when it comes to weeding out the ones with `#f518e2` and `#22f1e6` it's a little beyond what I know about regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to match all lines where `{` is at the start of the line, and `}` at the end of the line and match all lines in between that do not have either `#f518e2` or `#22f1e6` using a negative lookahead.

Note that this pattern works for the given examples, but does not take any nesting or data structure into account.

```
^.*{(?:\r?\n(?!.*#(?:f518e2|22f1e6)\b).*)*\r?\n}
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `.*{` Match the whole line and `{` at the end
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!.*#(?:f518e2|22f1e6)\b).*` Assert that the line does not contain the colors and match the whole line
- `)*` Close the non capture group and repeat 0+ times
- `\r?\n` Match a newline
- `}` Match `{`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TYOq5c/1)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use JavaScript to do such a task. I've including an example for your studies:

```js
//<[CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
function hexNum(x){
  switch(x.toUpperCase()){
    case 'A':
      return 10;
    case 'B':
      return 11;
    case 'C':
      return 12;
    case 'D':
      return 13;
    case 'E':
      return 14;
    case 'F':
      return 15;
    default:
      return +x;
  }
}
function hexToRGBArray(hex){
  let s, r = [];
  if(hex.match(/^#?[\dA-F]{6}$/i)){
    s = hex.replace(/^#/, '').split('');
    for(let i=0,q=1; i<6; i+=2,q+=2){
      r.push(hexNum(s[i])*16+hexNum(s[q]));
    }
  }
  else if(hex.match(/^#?[\dA-F]{3}/i)){
    s = hex.replace(/^#/, '').split('');
    for(let i=0,h; i<3; i++){
      h = hexNum(s[i]); r.push(h*16+h);
    }
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('invalid hexadecimal');
  }
  return r;
}
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
// stack overflow is including nodes you won't see in real world
const all = document.body.querySelectorAll('*');
const avoid1 = hexToRGBArray('#f518e2').join(), avoid2 = hexToRGBArray('#22f1e6').join();
let s;
for(let n of all){ // n being node
  s = getComputedStyle(n).color.replace(/^.+\(|\).*$/g, '').split(/\s*,\s*/).join();
  if(s !== avoid1 && s !== avoid2){
    console.log(n.textContent);
    // n is node
  }
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
div{
  color:#ab7722;
}
#test1{
  color:#f518e2;
}
#test4{
   color:#22f1e6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='test1'>nope</div>
  <div id='test2'>got this one</div>
  <div id='test3'>and this one</div>
  <div id='test4'>not this one</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that in the real world `document.body` would only access that which is in the `body`. Stack Overflow must have something else in mind. They should fix it.

Comment: This is really cool, thanks for sharing. I actually just want to select and delete all of the declarations blocks without those colors in a code editor so I can paste the optimized code as text into a larger project.

Comment: Use your editor. It takes regular expressions, if it's any good.

Comment: I know, I'm trying to construct a regular expression that will select every declaration block that doesn't have those hex values.

Comment: You could use `.+{[^}]+(#f518e2|#22f1e6)[^}]+}` in Komodo and replace all with nothing and the rest will be left over.